# mySQl login with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication, passwords

I have a Homepage with a login with $hash = password_hash($accountpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);.
(http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php)

The password is saved as hash begins with $2y$.

Then i created the login in C#:

```
 //crypting the PW that user enter
        string cryptedPassword = Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt(textBox_password.Text);


        string user = textBox_username.Text;
        string pass = cryptedPassword;
        if (user == "" || pass == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected ! Please fill up all the fields");
            return;
        }
        bool r = validate_login(user, pass);
        if (r)
            MessageBox.Show("Correct Login Credentials");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Login Credentials"+cryptedPassword);
```

my validate method:

```
private bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users where username=@user and password=@pass";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (login.Read())
        {
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

at Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt(textBox_password.Text) is worng. I become a hash starts with $2a$

can anyone help to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt` method you need to specify a 2nd parameter salt, if one isn't provided then a random one is generated for you.  Obviously you are going to get different random values on subsequent calls.

Alternativly you could get the Crypter library to check the password provided against the hash:

```
if (Crypter.CheckPassword(password, cryptedPassword)) {
  // Valid password code here
  return true;
} else {
  // Invalid password code here
  return false;
}
```

You will obviously need to read the crypted password from the db, but I believe this method will mean you don't need to provide/store a salt for the password hash.

HTH

Comment: hmm the php script is not my work. how can i find out the 2. parameter?

Comment: Either use something like `Crypter.Blowfish.GenerateSalt(6)` and store that value, or use a string of your own choosing (less secure).  I have updated my answer to include an alternative method which should enable you to perform the check without needing to store the salt.